# VisualStudio Code is completly black when started

Tags: screen, visual-studio-code

When i started VSCode it is completely black and you can't see anything. But when i enter something and exit the program it asks if you want to save the changes. And the words I entered were saved! Everything is working but the screen is just completely black.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

[image: Black screen pic]

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's a GPU issue that can be fixed by running VS Code from command line and passing in the disable-gpu flag:

```
code --disable-gpu
```

Context: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/supporting/faq#_vs-code-main-window-is-blank

Comment: After using this disable gpu flag it still shows the blank screen, what to do?